# Is it possible to change internetMessageId when preparing o365 reply?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I can't change `internetMessageId` in a draft reply.

1. I prepared draft reply

```
POST /me/messages/<id>/createReply

<empty body>
=>
201

{
  "id": "<reply-id>"
  "isDraft": true
  ...
}
```

2. I tried to update the draft with own message-id and got the error.

```
PATCH /me/messages/<reply-id>

{
  "internetMessageId": "<someid@somedomain.com>"
}
=>
400

{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorInvalidPropertySet",
    "message": "Set action is invalid for property.",
    ...
  }
}
```

But the [ms doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-update) states that `internetMessageId` "Updatable only if isDraft = true", so the update should work.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have verified that this is actually an issue. We're scheduling work to get this fixed but no ETA right now.

In the mean time, if you actually just use /reply directly on a message id you can set the internetMessageId. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/conversationthread-reply?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/threads/{id}/reply
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 1131

{
  "post": {
    "body": {
      "contentType": "",
      "content": "content-value"
    }
  }
}
```